# Xamarin profiler crashing - mlpd file exists but is empty

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

When starting the Xamarin profiler it successfully starts the application on my iPhone device.

However before the profiling begins I get an error at the bottom of the window that states:

[image]

Afterwards it states

> Sorry something went wrong. An error occurred on client profile while executing a post topic

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Well something is wrong with the Provision Profile you are creating Either Create it again or Upload a little bit more than this so we can understand what the actual problem is.